Enabling video display without a `/proc/fb` device
Under Linux/Ubuntu: I had an impression that to have video output (either in console mode or GUI mode), there must be a fbdev listed in /proc/fb.
But today on my system, I installed a NVIDIA GTX1650 card, and under /etc/modprobe.d, the options nvidia-drm modeset=1 and options nvidia-drm fbdev=1 are disabled. After reboot, the system shows that /proc/fb is empty, but the X11/Gnome desktop is showing up correctly.
I guess I must have a mis-understanding of the implications of /proc/fb content. Can you please give me some hints on that?

I had an impression that to have video output (either in console mode or GUI mode): That impression is wrong.

Sure, I knew it's wrong. Would you please give some educational information on this aspect? Thanks!

I don't know what to say there – it's simply not the case. The graphical interface you see has nothing to do with fbdev.
